# How can Univocity Parsers read a .csv file when the headers are not on the first line?

Tags: parsing, csv

How can Univocity Parsers read a .csv file when the headers are not on the first line?

There are errors if the first line in the .csv file is not the headers.

The code and stack trace are below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.*;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;


public class UnivocityParsers {

public Reader getReader(String relativePath) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath), "Windows-1252");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read input", e);
    }
}


public void columnSelection() {
    RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setSkipEmptyLines(true);

    // Here we select only the columns "Price", "Year" and "Make".
    // The parser just skips the other fields
    parserSettings.selectFields("AUTHOR", "ISBN");

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.parse(getReader("list2.csv"));

    List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();

    String[] strings = rows.get(0);

    System.out.print(strings[0]);

}


public static void main(String arg[]) {

    UnivocityParsers univocityParsers = new UnivocityParsers();

    univocityParsers.columnSelection();


}


}
```

Stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: Error processing input: java.lang.IllegalStateException - Unknown field names: [author, isbn]. Available fields are: [list of books by author - created today]
```

Here is the file being parsed:

```
List of books by Author - Created today
"REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",0345391802,5.95
"1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",0465026567,9.95
"1998/07/15","Timothy ""The Parser"" Campbell",0968411304,18.99
"1999/12/03","Richard Friedman",0060630353,5.95
"2001/09/19","Karen Armstrong",0345384563,9.95
"2002/06/23","David Jones",0198504691,9.95
"2002/06/23","Julian Jaynes",0618057072,12.50
"2003/09/30","Scott Adams",0740721909,4.95
"2004/10/04","Benjamin Radcliff",0804818088,4.95
"2004/10/04","Randel Helms",0879755725,4.50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, on 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT you can do this:

```
settings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(1);
```

On version 1.5.6 you can do this to skip the first line and correctly grab the headers:

```
RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor(){
        @Override
        public void processStarted(ParsingContext context) {
            super.processStarted(context);
            context.skipLines(1);
        }
    };
```

An alternative is to comment the first line if your input file (if you have control over how the file is generated) by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line you want to discard:

```
#List of books by Author - Created today
```

Comment: When trying the solution code above  with univocity-parsers-1.5.6.jar, there's error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown field names: [author, isbn, review_date]. Available fields are: [1985/01/21, douglas adams, 0345391802, 5.95]`. When trying the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT solution by adding pom.xml from that snapshot to the IntelliJ project: `Error:(53, 23) java: cannot find symbol symbol: method setNumberOfRowsToSkip(int) location: variable parserSettings of type com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings`. Also, IntelliJ doesnt find pom.xml plugin: `<artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>`.

Comment: The 1.5.6 solution works (i.e. overriding the `processStartedMethod`) and I tested it myself with the code you posted. Apparently you applied other changes as well and it grabbed the third row to use as headers instead of the second one. On the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version, you don't need to copy the pom file over, that will never work. You either update your own pom.xml or grab the jar from the [https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20151111.095007-18.jar)

Comment: I put `univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20151111.095007-18.jar` into the project library, however, when I call the new method with: `parserSettings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(1);` an error occurs: `Cannot resolve method 'setNumberOfRowsToSkip(int)'`.

Comment: Sorry, I sent a bad link. This is what you need:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20151114.062302-19.jar

Comment: Hi, this link: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20151114.062302-19.jar actually leads to a 404. Is a working link available?

Comment: Grab the latest snapshot from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/